# Create a url which contains '&'

Tags: java, android, url

When i call a webservice i pass certain values in that url.

Example:

```
https://website.com/webserviceName/login?userName=user&password=pass
```

but what if the values have "&" in them.When i form such an url which contains an item with '&' the url breaks at that point returns a fault code. How do i over come this problem.

Example:

```
https://website.com/webserviceName/login?userName=user&user&password=pass
```

the problem with this url is that it breaks at the first '&'

The problem can be solved by using `URLEncoder.encode(urlXml)`
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm

Thanx everyone

Comment: use %26 in place of second check this for unicode  http://unicode-table.com/en/#0026

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must [encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the ampersand `&` with `%26`. So your URL will become

```
https://website.com/webserviceName/login?userName=user%26user&password=pass
```

If your username is not fixed and you want to use [`URLEncoder.encode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) as @SudhanshuUmalkar suggested, you should encode the arguments only

```
String url = "https://website.com/webserviceName/login?userName="
             + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8") + "&password="
             + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
```

Since `encode(String)` is deprecated, you should use `encode(String, "UTF-8")` or whatever your character set is.

Answer (score 2):

Use URLEncoder.encode() method.

url = "https://website.com/webserviceName/login?" + URLEncoder.encode("userName=user&user&password=pass", "UTF-8");

Comment: The encode here won't encode the ampersands. They will remain literal &s.

Comment: How is that `URLEncoder` going to make a distinction between the first and second ampersand...?!? ;-)

Comment: You can put the value of userName in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have code working with literal ampersands in it. Your code could break because you don't provide a valid key-value parameter pair:

```
https://website.com/webserviceName/login?userName=user&user&password=pass
                                                       ^ this shouldn't be like this
```

The code below works in production:

```
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://www.example.com/sub/folder/api.php?time=%s&lang=%s&action=test";
String.format (API.DATA_URL, "" + now, language)
```